# is it pointless to stack models of different data types/structure?

Tags: machine-learning, stacking

I am studying ensemble methods machine learning, in particular I am focusing on stacking.

In stacking different models are used to get an output. Then all the outputs are 'combined' together to build a model.
So, first of all, I guess the models MUST be different between each other (does it make sense?). Once we have these models, does it make sense to apply them to different data types/structures?

UPDATE: For “data structures” I am just saying different methods that learn different models (e.g. a degree 2 polynomial, a degree 4 polynomial, a KNN classifier, a SVM, etc.).

Comment: What do you mean by applying the models to different data/structures?

Comment: A concrete example will go a long way toward clarifying your question. Otherwise, it might be closed until you edit the detail into the question.

Comment: @gunes Yeah, OK, the question is using jargon that not everyone knows. However, that jargon becomes clear when one takes the time to look it up, or for that matter, if one looks at the `stacking` tag that is already attached to the question. So, I agree with you that the question seems vague, but actually the answer below should clarify things a bit.

Comment: @Carl, I read your answer but (sorry in advance if I misunderstood something), it doesn't seem to answer the question. Instead it describes what stacking is. But the question OP is asking "does it make sense to apply them to different data-types/structures". I don't know what is meant by data-type/structure, and these words are not mentioned in your answer either?

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius True at the point at which I was in the write-up. Sometimes I save intermediate answers so I don't lose them when I go surfing for further information. Read it again, please, and tell me if it is OK now.

Comment: @Carl Sorry again - too late, I voted to close and seems like my vote was 3rd close vote already, so the question is closed now... But I think your answer assumes data-type/structure means "different dataset". So IMO it remains unclear until OP clarifies what he has in mind. And then, with bagging for example (i.e. Random Forest), it's acceptable to train different models on different samples and different subsets of features. I don't immediately see why stacking would be different in that regard?

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius "The point of stacking is to explore a space of different models for the same problem." as below. Moreover the procedure listed examines a single data set. This does not exclude the possibility of examining multiple data sets but does not specify how that would be done within the context of stacking, which clearly relates to different models for the data, for meta-analysis of data sets for machine learning, please see the link I provided. Clearly that does not answer every possibility, but it is an answer to the question.

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius Regarding Random Forest, consider this sentence "Next, we define the hyperparameters for tuning along with the models. We use random forest, LightGBM, and XGBoost in the following code because they typically perform the best. First, we import and instantiate the classes for the models, then we define some parameters to input into the grid search function." from [IBM](https://developer.ibm.com/articles/stack-machine-learning-models-get-better-results/), That is, Random Forest is a "model" for stacking within machine learning for unique data.

Comment: @Carl Random Forest is an ensemble method that trains thousands of classifiers, where each classifier uses a different subset of the original dataset, and then combines those classifiers via bagging. I didn't see a reason, in your answer, that would suggest these same classifiers cannot be combined using stacking instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131149/discussion-between-karolis-koncevicius-and-carl).

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius It would appear that Random Forest is a "model" like XGBoost is a model and that stacking combines models.

Comment: Concerning the update, so you mean different models but the SAME data?

Answer (score 3):

Using [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure)

> In computer science, a data structure is a data organization,
> management, and storage format that enables efficient access and
> modification. More precisely, a data structure is a collection of data
> values, the relationships among them, and the functions or operations
> that can be applied to the data, i.e., it is an algebraic structure
> about data.

Calling things like "a degree 2 polynomial, a degree 4 polynomial, a KNN classifier, a SVM, etc." is unfortunate. Those are machine learning algorithms, they have nothing to do with data structures.

Machine learning *model* is a mathematical representation of the data, partially assumed (structure), partially learned from the data (parameters). Things such as linear regression, polynomial regression, $k$-NN, random forest, would all be refered as models. For learning the model we have machine learning *algorithms*. People would often use the terms exchangably.

By stacking models we mean stacking any kind of models. You could stack dofferent linear regression models, that differ by the data that was used for training them, and hence by the parameters, but also you can stack together $k$-NN, linear regression, SVM, and random forest. Usually, stacking diverse models gives better results than for homogeneus models, so it would be perfectly reasonable to stack together $k$-NN, SVM, and polynomial regression.

Answer (score 1):

First, let us review what stacking is. Then we can answer the question. Stacking is a machine learning variation of meta-analysis. I don't claim any originality for [this answer from the geeksforgeeks site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stacking-in-machine-learning/), which says,

"There are many ways to ensemble models, the widely known models are Bagging or Boosting. Bagging allows multiple similar models with high variance are averaged to decrease variance. Boosting builds multiple incremental models to decrease the bias, while keeping variance small.

Stacking (sometimes called Stacked Generalization) is a different paradigm. The point of stacking is to explore a space of different models for the same problem. The idea is that you can attack a learning problem with different types of models which are capable to learn some part of the problem, but not the whole space of the problem. So, you can build multiple different learners and you use them to build an intermediate prediction, one prediction for each learned model. Then you add a new model which learns from the intermediate predictions the same target.
This final model is said to be stacked on the top of the others, hence the name. Thus, you might improve your overall performance, and **often you end up with a model which is better than any individual intermediate model. Notice however, that it does not give you any guarantee, as is often the case with any machine learning technique.**"

Note my bolding of text above; no guarantees it works. Moreover, they outline a procedure for stacking:

"How stacking works?

1. We split the training data into K-folds just like K-fold cross-validation.
2. A base model is fitted on the K-1 parts and predictions are made for Kth part.
3. We do for each part of the training data.
4. The base model is then fitted on the whole train data set to calculate its performance on the test set.
5. We repeat the last 3 steps for other base models.
6. Predictions from the train set are used as features for the second level model.
7. Second level model is used to make a prediction on the test set."

Also, see this other article [same website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stacking-in-machine-learning-2/?ref=rp).

**Now the answer** Stacking uses different models for the same data.
To combine results from different data sets would be a more general meta-analysis, and there appears to have been [some work](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10956-020-09875-z) on that topic. The OP asks **Once we have these models, does it make sense to apply them to different data types/structures?** It makes sense to go through the same procedure from scratch. That is, if the problem changes, the models needed will be different. If the problem doesn't change and there is merely more of the same type of data, then the analysis can be repeated on that larger data set.